# REPLACE quote ' WITH % symbol so that I can query

Tags: sql-server-2008, replace

I have a value in column with string: `Children's play ground`. I want to replace `'` with `%`. So I use

```
replace(columnname, '''', '%')
replace(columnname, '', '%')
```

doesn't work either.

Comment: Oh Sorry in SQL server 2008R2

Comment: SET @CATEGORYNAME ='CATEGORYNAME' + REPLACE(@CATEGORYNAME,'+ CHAR(39) +','%') </p> I try this too

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR(100) = 'Children''s play ground'

CREATE TABLE #TMP(TEXT1 VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #TMP
SELECT @NAME

SELECT TEXT1 FROM #TMP

SELECT REPLACE(TEXT1,'''','%') FROM #TMP
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(50);
SET @str = 'Children''s play ground'
SELECT @str
SET @str = REPLACE(@str, '''', '%')
SELECT @str;
```

Comment: I only worked if I declared 'Children''s play ground but it is already declared in list as 'Children's Play Ground' so I can't change it to new 'Children''s with two colon so with one colon 'Children's' to change to 'children%s' doesn't not worked.